# what is wrong with my code, trying to get first element text jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Look at my code, I want to make it like that when a user click the table tr, I will get the first td text, so jquery I use first() and then text(), but it echo out both td 1 and td apple. I only want to get the first td text, what did I do wrong? Appreciate.

```js
var gridtable = $('.gridtable');

gridtable.click(function(){
  var name = $(this).first().text();
  alert('name');
  })
```

```html
 <tr class="gridtable">
       <td>1</td>
       <td >apple</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr class="gridtable">
       <td>2</td>
       <td >banana</td> 
 </tr>
```

Comment: first does not return the first child, it returns the first matching queried element - in your case, the tr - as in the click function there is only one element in $(this), you could do `$(this).children().first().text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside handler `this` refers to the clicked `tr` applying **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)** method will retrieve the same `tr` itself . Instead, you need to filter out the nested `td` element. You can use the **[`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**  pseudo-class selector to get the first element.

```
var gridtable = $('.gridtable:first');
gridtable.click(function(){
    // get the first element within the context
    var name = $('td:first', this).text();
    alert(name);
});
```

---

```js
var gridtable = $('.gridtable');

gridtable.click(function() {
  var name = $('td:first',this).text();
  alert(name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>apple</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gridtable">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>banana</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var gridtable = $('.gridtable');

gridtable.click(function(){
        var name = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        alert(name);
  });
```

Comment: surely it should be `alert(name)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are attaching your click handler at the tr level, you'll need to use the [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function to select all tds within the tr and then select the first td:

```
var name = $(this).find('td').first().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`var gridtable` is referring to your `tr` elements, so when `$element.click` is raised, `gridtable.first()` is locating the first element with class `.gridtable`

You could use `.gridtable.children()` to get the children of `gridtable` and use the `.first()` after that

Please have a look to this example: https://jsfiddle.net/gnc9t1p2/1/

### Edit 1 -

As @JaromandaX said, you should use `var name = $(this)...` to get the clicked row.

Comment: don't use gridtable - that has multiple tr's - in the click you want to use `$(this)` as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help out you, it's working for me.

```
 var gridtable = $('.gridtable');
       gridtable.click(function(){
       var name = $(this).find("td:first").text();// for only first td
                              or 
       var name =   $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();// you can change index number like  eq(0) ,eq(1) for nect td
                alert(name);
      })
```